# How to grab a reference to each image's alt tag and display it as a caption below the corresponding image in a lightbox gallery

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I am trying to grab a reference to an gallery image's alt tag within a jQuery lightbox and display it as a caption just below the image after it jumps to the link to the larger image and plops it into the lightbox.

```
$(function(){

    $('.gallery a').on('click', function(e){
        var image_source = $(this).attr('href');
        var text = $('.gallery a img').attr('alt'); 

        $('#content').html('<img src="' + image_source + text + '">');
        /* .html('<p style="color:#fff;">' + alt_text + '</p>');
-----------above was the other method I tried which didn't work so I commented it out--  -----*/

        $('#lightbox').show();

        e.preventDefault();
    });//End Gallery


    $('#lightbox').on('click', function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $('#content img').remove();
    });
});//End Ready
```

I will, of course, want the corresponding image's alt tag to display for the corresponding larger image that loads when the gallery thumbnail is clicked.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance!
Here is the JSFiddle for it:
http://jsfiddle.net/graphicsinc/37A4y/13/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `alt_text` shoud be `text` **or** rename variale name `text` to `alt_text`.

**EDIT**: Code shoud like this:

```
$(function() {

    $('.gallery a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var image_source = $(this).attr('href');
        var alt_text = $('.gallery a img').attr('alt');

        $('#content')
            //.html('<img src="' + image_source + text + '">');
            .html('<p style="color:#fff;">' + alt_text + '</p>');
        $('#lightbox').show();
    });//End Gallery

    $('#lightbox').on('click', function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $('#content img').remove();
    });

});//End Ready
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37A4y/14/)

**EDIT2**: If you want add `alt` attribute to `img`, it shoud look like this

```
$('#content').html('<img src="' + image_source + '" alt="' + alt_text + '">');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37A4y/17/)

Comment: The "alt_text" was what I named the variable prior to "text". It is in a line of code that I experimented with to see if it would work, and to no avail. As you can see, that line of code is commented out. If I understand you correctly, are you saying not to use "text" because it is a "reserved word";in other words: a jQuery entity? 

I'm just wondering if I can even select the IMG tag's alt attribute in the manner which I am trying to:<br><br>
    `$('gallery a img').attr('alt');?`

Comment: Ok, I changed the variable name to alt_text....and....nothing happened. [http://jsfiddle.net/37A4y/16/] Suggestions?

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks, Shaddow!